# I want to show Error message in ReactJS Form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ant-design-pro

I am new to reactJS i want to show Error message when someone leave empty filed. Form is already validated but not able to display error message.I Copied this form code from (`ant-design`) i will share it link to view original form and it working fine but in my form the error message is not working . 
Original Form link [Form Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/0yr24x50lp)

**My Form Code**

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import Input from 'antd/lib/input';

const FormCard = styled.div`
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.41, 0.094, 0.54, 0.07) 0s;
  margin-top: 30px;
`;

const FormItem = styled.div`
  font-family: 'Chinese Quote', -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI',
    'PingFang SC', 'Hiragino Sans GB', 'Microsoft YaHei', 'Helvetica Neue',
    Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji',
    'Segoe UI Symbol';
  font-size: 14px;
  font-variant: tabular-nums;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 18px;
  vertical-align: top;
`;

class RegisterStepOne extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { getFieldDecorator } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <FormCard>
          <FormItem label="E-mail">
            {getFieldDecorator('firstName', {
              rules: [
                {
                  required: true,
                  message: 'Please input your First name!',
                  whitespace: true,
                },
              ],
            })(<Input placeholder="First name" />)}
          </FormItem>
          <FormItem label="E-mail">
            {getFieldDecorator('lastName', {
              rules: [
                {
                  required: true,
                  message: 'Please input your Last name!',
                  whitespace: true,
                },
              ],
            })(<Input placeholder="Last name" />)}
          </FormItem>
          <FormItem label="E-mail">
            {getFieldDecorator('email', {
              rules: [
                {
                  type: 'email',
                  message: 'The input is not valid E-mail!',
                },
                {
                  required: true,
                  message: 'Please input your E-mail!',
                },
              ],
            })(<Input placeholder="Email" />)}
          </FormItem>

          <FormItem>
            {getFieldDecorator('lastPosition', {
              rules: [
                {
                  required: true,
                  message: 'Please input your Last Position!',
                  whitespace: true,
                },
              ],
            })(<Input placeholder="Present or last position" />)}
          </FormItem>

          <FormItem>
            {getFieldDecorator('lastCompany', {
              rules: [
                {
                  required: true,
                  message: 'Please input your Last Company!',
                  whitespace: true,
                },
              ],
            })(<Input placeholder="Present or last Company" />)}
          </FormItem>
        </FormCard>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default RegisterStepOne;
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Ant design components, you should import them first

```
import { Form,  Input} from 'antd';
const FormItem = Form.Item;
```

Also, replace this

```
export default RegisterStepOne;
```

with

```
const RegisterStepOne = Form.create()(RegisterStepOne);

ReactDOM.render(<RegisterStepOne />, mountNode);
```